# How do I know when kendo ui grid is fully loaded and displayed?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

According to this post: [Telerik Forum - How do I know when grid is fully loaded and displayed?](http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-do-i-know-when-grid-is-fully-loaded-and-displayed-)

I need to know if the grid is fully loaded and displayed.
I just know about the dataBound and change event but at the time of the events the temlates are not fully loaded.

The forum post is nearby 3 years old.

Does anyone know if a workaround has come with updates?

Comment: What do you have in the Grid templates? Can you share some demo?

Comment: This really sucks. The dataBound event seems to be executed when the grid's dataSource receive the data and parses it into its own strucutre. But at the time dataBound event is called, the rows aren't rendered in the dom  structure yet. And the grid have no other event for that. It is a shame, really. What I do to workaround that, is call a timeout of 1 milisec inside the dataBound. It is enough to javascript render the table in dom. If you have too many rows and you're afraid of users' browser performance, you can increase that time. That's awful I know, but it works for me.

Comment: The Grid dataBound event is fired **after** rendering of the table rows. You can verify this here: http://dojo.telerik.com/ulAhU Can you share an example that exhibits the opposite behavior?

Comment: Hi @dimodi, have you ever set a debugger on the dataBound event? if you do that you'll see, that the event is triggerd before the table and its templates are fully loaded.

Comment: I'll try to set up a demo to show my issue.
In addition: The only thing i would like to do is, showing an loading indicator while the grid is not fully loaded.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown thanks for your help. It seems, that this is the only way i can handle it.

Comment: @P.Ommer want an answer of that ?

Comment: @P.Ommer Here is an updated version of my example, as well as a video which shows that the new table rows are rendered at the time dataBound is fired: http://dojo.telerik.com/ulAhU/3 and http://screencast.com/t/X1aiVq9D